# Can not import theano after installation

Tags: python, theano

The code is like this

```
$ sudo pip install theano
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): theano in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from theano)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.11 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from theano)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.9.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from theano)
Cleaning up...
~$ python -c"import theano;theano.test()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named theano
```

I am sorry that I am still a freshman both in this site and linux.

Comment: Please, post the output of `python --version` and `sudo python -m pip install theano`

Comment: trump@trump-unicorn:~$ python --version
Python 2.7.6

Comment: ~$ sudo python -m pip install theano
[sudo] password for trump: 
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): theano in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.1 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from theano)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scipy>=0.11 in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from theano)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): six>=1.9.0 in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/six-1.10.0-py2.7.egg (from theano)
Cleaning up...

Comment: These are the output, although it is only one version in the output, I still thing that there are two version in my laptop(2.7 and 3.4),but I do not know how to deal with it.

Comment: Could you also post the output of `python -c "import sys; print sys.path"`?

Comment: it seemed that the packages installed by pip are not available, so i add the path, but it still did not work, so i came to github to download it and unpackaged it, than I setup it successfully. Still thanks a lot!

Comment: You may write this as answer and accept it in order to help people with the same problem

Comment: Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

That may due to the the two versions of python, so firstly I removed one and add the path for python to get the packages installed by pip, but it still does not help. Finally I came to to github to download it and unpackaged it, aftering test for around 30 minutes, it came out no errors, which means I setup it successfully.

Comment: This too effect in fact!

Answer (score 1):

After removing the previous version, I installed it as follows:
(http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_ubuntu.html)

```
git clone git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git
cd Theano
python setup.py develop --user
cd ..
```